# Matlab is not doing correct calculations

Tags: matlab

I have a problem with matlab and i'm almost sure I've seen it before somewhere and gone around it, but now I want to solve it... When I'm doing a simple calculation:

```
>> 14336*0.005
```

You'll get the expected answer:

```
ans = 71.6800
```

but when using format long:

```
format long; ans = 71.680000000000007
```

It doesn't seem to be a problem for matlab:

```
ans==71.68 = 1
```

But if I do one more calculation:

```
ans/0.005 = 1.433600000000000e+04
ans==14336 = 0
ans-14336 = 1.818989403545856e-12
```

Do anyone know a solution to get rid of the difference of 1.81e-12 of the original value and final value? I guess it's due to datatypes and stuff but is there a solution?

//Lucas

Comment: Solution to what? I don't think you state clearly what the issue is...

Comment: Welcome to the world of floating point arithmetic.  Please see the duplicate answer I have linked (Why is 24.0000 not equal to 24.0000) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the solution is not to do equality test on floating-point precision numbers. Instead, compare the absolute value of the difference to a small threshold value (e.g. [`eps`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html)). See the [MATLAB FAQ](http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#Why_is_0.3_-_0.2_-_0.1_.28or_similar.29_not_equal_to_zero.3F).